# Adding a new record when form value is EOF

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, record, eof

I've got a search bar and a submit button that takes 3 strings and pulls the record on another form from a query. When the record exists in the table the query runs, when it doesn't, I get a an error:

*You entered an expression that has no value*, that's because the query is looking for a record that doesn't exist.

It's my intention to create a new record when the query cannot find one. I did this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    If Recordset.EOF = True Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Exit Sub
    End If
        
... do some more stuff that's not relavant ...
```

But this fails on Do.Cmd with the error, *You cannot go to the specified record.*

I was able to determine that when the form loads, its EOF whatever that means, so I looked it up on learn.microsoft.com. Under EOF, it states:

*An OpenRecordset method internally invokes a MoveFirst method. Therefore, using an OpenRecordset method on an empty set of records sets the BOF and EOF properties to True. (See the following table for the behavior of a failed MoveFirst method.)*

I've been looking at ways to add a new record instead of the error and not got far. How do I resolve the error whist staying on the form? It's my understanding I need to make EOF.value False somehow.

EDIT Tried this
Recordset.AddNew
Error: This action was cancelled by an associated object

Comment: `recordset.addnew` is how.

Comment: Now I get an error saying: This action was cancelled by an associated object

Comment: `EOF` means **End Of File**, `BOF` means **Beginning Of File**. Your code is not opening a recordset object. The code works for me. Might what to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.

Comment: It seems like I cannot even go to movelast or move first. I assume this is to do with the record being null that's being loaded?

Comment: Where is your recordset? Are you trying to pull it from the form?

Comment: Turns out I had Me.AllowAdditions = False on, ffs